# Ruby: sum vs. inject(:+) produces different results

Tags: arrays, ruby, inject

I've noticed `array.sum` and `array.inject(:+)` produce different results. What's the reason for this?

```
a = [10, 1.1, 6.16]

a.inject(:+)
# => 17.259999999999998

a.sum
# => 17.26
```

Comment: Rounding - see "is floating point math broken" questions: `sum` probably uses native code; if so, it can be optimized, but also means it doesn't have to do the *exact* same sequence of rounding to a double-64 each step. What is the result of `[10, 15, 1.1, 2, 6.16, 1].sum`? What about `10 + 15 + 1.1 + 2 + 6.16 + 1`? Those should show the same behavior "deviations" as the code in the question.

Comment: The order in which these are added has an impact on what value you get out due to quirks of floating point values. I have a feeling `sum` works in a different order.

Comment: TIL we should prefer `sum` not only for performance but for accuracy when adding floating point numbers, thanks for this. It's pretty informative to look at the amount of complexity that exists in the [C implementation](https://github.com/mrkn/enumerable-statistics/blob/master/ext/enumerable/statistics/extension/statistics.c#L636)  of something as (seemingly) trivial as `Array#sum`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C implementation of `Array#sum` delegates to the [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) when some of its inputs are floating point numbers.

This algorithm ...

> ...significantly reduces the numerical error in the total obtained by adding a sequence of finite precision floating point numbers, compared to the obvious approach. This is done by keeping a separate running compensation (a variable to accumulate small errors).
>
> *-- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)*

See [Array#sum](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mrkn/enumerable-statistics/master/Array%3Asum) and the [implementation on Github](https://github.com/mrkn/enumerable-statistics/blob/master/ext/enumerable/statistics/extension/statistics.c#L687).